# Trouble with databases

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am having a problem with databases in android apps. I am unable to get even the demo program in the text book to work. The java class for the database is not being found by the program. I get a message saying cannot resolve symbol.

I have gone as far as downloading the sample code for the link provided and I cannot solve this.

Here is the code for the java class.

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DBAdapter {

    static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";
    static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyDB";
    static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "contacts";
    static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
            "create table contacts (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
                    + "name text not null, email text not null);";
    final Context context;
    DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
    SQLiteDatabase db;

    public DBAdapter(Context ctx)
    {
        this.context = ctx;
        DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }
    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context)
        {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
        {
            try {
                db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
        {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS contacts");
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }
    //---opens the database---
    public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException
    {
        db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }
    //---closes the database---
    public void close()
    {
        DBHelper.close();
    }
    //---insert a contact into the database---
    public long insertContact(String name, String email)
    {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_NAME, name);
        initialValues.put(KEY_EMAIL, email);
        return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }
    //---deletes a particular contact---
    public boolean deleteContact(long rowId)
    {
        return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }
    //---retrieves all the contacts---
    public Cursor getAllContacts()
    {
        return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME,
                KEY_EMAIL}, null, null, null, null, null);
    }
    //---retrieves a particular contact---
    public Cursor getContact(long rowId) throws SQLException
    {
        Cursor mCursor =
                db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                                KEY_NAME, KEY_EMAIL}, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null,
                        null, null, null, null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
    }
    //---updates a contact---
    public boolean updateContact(long rowId, String name, String email)
    {
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put(KEY_NAME, name);
        args.put(KEY_EMAIL, email);
        return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }
}
```

and here's the code for the main screen.

```
package biz.goodrich.daniel.databases;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this); //---add a contact---
        db.open();
        long id = db.insertContact("Jennifer Ann", "jenniferann@jfdimarzio.com");
        id = db.insertContact("Oscar Diggs", "oscar@oscardiggs.com");
        db.close();

    }
}
```

The methods in the DBadapter show as error free in android studio and yet none of the activities can find them.

Comment: It would be good to post the log file with the specific error details. The "cannot resolve symbol" error message is likely pointing to something else other than your database code, which you will first need to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

From testing your code I believe that your issues is that the package used (i.e. has not been coded) in the DBAdapter class is the cause of your issue.

Add the line `package biz.goodrich.daniel.databases;` as the very first line of the DBAdapter class.

i.e.

instead of

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DBAdapter { 
.......... the rest of your code
```

use :-

```
package biz.goodrich.daniel.databases; //<<<< THIS LINE ADDED

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DBAdapter {
.......... the rest of your code
```